# Wordpress Calendar Failure

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a calendar plugin and edited the plugin output for my own design. No i see all the time the same date. Everytime the 1. January. When i take another date, it will show me the 1. january.

```
$datevalue = tribe_events_event_schedule_details();
    preg_match_all('/<span class="tribe-event-date-start">.*?<\/span>/',   
    $datevalue, $datearray);
    $dates = explode("-",$datearray[0][0]);
    $dates = '"'.$datearray[0][0];
    $datess = substr($dates,38,10);
    $date = date("d",strtotime($datess));
    $month = date("M",strtotime($datess));
    $event_output .= apply_filters( 'ecs_event_date_tag_start', '<li class="timelist"><div class="duration time calendarss"><a href="' . tribe_get_event_link() . '" rel="bookmark" >', $atts, $post ) ." <center style='padding-top: 32px;padding: 15px;line-height: 15px;'><b>$date <br> $month</b></center> ".
                                           apply_filters( 'ecs_event_date_tag_end', '</div></a>', $atts, $post );
                                $event_output .= apply_filters( 'ecs_event_title_tag_start', '', $atts, $post ) .
                                                apply_filters( 'ecs_event_list_title_link_start', '<a style="font-size:13px !important; color:#FF4C4C" href="' . tribe_get_event_link() . '" rel="bookmark"><div style="    padding-top: 15px;">', $atts, $post ) . apply_filters( 'ecs_event_list_title', get_the_title(), $atts, $post ) . apply_filters( 'ecs_event_list_title_link_end', '</div></a></li><div class="clearfix"></div>', $atts, $post ) .
                                           apply_filters( 'ecs_event_title_tag_end', '</h4>', $atts, $post );
```

Is there any failure in my code that i edited?

Comment: Your fiddle link is not code, so please don't format it as if it's code. Secondly, if you can make a Fiddle then you can also make a stack snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Is there any failure in my code that i edited?` - I don't know, is there? How can we tell? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edit the question

Comment: You really shouldn't edit vendor code like that.  Use your own CSS to style it for 'your design'.  Reason is, when the author of that plugin updates it, and you apply the update, your edits will be gone.  Meaning you constantly have to re-implement your edits every time you upgrade that plugin.  It's no longer maintainable.

Comment: Show the original code too so others can compare the two.